# How to set defaultProp value based on value of other prop?

Tags: reactjs, react-proptypes

I have a component where the default value of one prop depends on the value of another prop (default or user provided). We can't do the following because we don't have access to `this`:

```
static defaultProps = {
    delay: this.props.trigger === 'hover' ? 100 : 0,
    trigger: 'hover'
};
```

How can I best do this?

Comment: Is it just the default value that is dependent or the prop as well

Comment: You may need to ask yourself if this is really a prop or actually a state property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd rather suggest you to:

- store that variable as an instance variable in the component's class
- evaluate if it is a state variable rather than a prop (or instance)

By the way in both cases you should check when new props arrive to the component and update it if needed.

I'd go for the state variable and write something like this:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    trigger: PropTypes.string,
  }

  static defaultProps = {
    trigger: 'hover',
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      delay: this.computeDelay(),
    }
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const { trigger: oldTrigger } = this.props;
    const { trigger } = nextProps;
    if (trigger !== oldTrigger) {
      this.setState({
        delay: this.computeDelay(),
      })
    }
  }

  computeDelay() {
    const { trigger } = this.props;
    return trigger === 'hover' ? 100 : 0;
  }

  render() {
    ...
  }
}
```

In this way you can use `this.state.delay` in the render method without taking care of determining its value.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it inside the render method.

```
render() {
  const delay = this.props.trigger === 'hover' ? 100 : 0;
  // Your other props

  return (
    <SomeComponent delay={delay} />
    // or
    <div>
      {/*...something else, use your delay */}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: actually I wanted to access this prop value in many instance methods and lifecycle hooks. Will I be required to save it to `this`? Although that would be a bad thing to do and will be unsafe once async rendering comes. That's why I wanted it to be inside props.

Comment: @mohsinulhaq You can save it to this, but you don't need to.  It only depends on trigger, you can use a method like getDelay() to get the delay value.

Answer (score 4):

Using a function component you can do it like this:

```
function MyComponent({
    trigger,
    delay: trigger === 'hover' ? 100 : 0,
}) {
  return <div>...</div>
}

MyComponent.propTypes = {
  trigger: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  delay: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
};
```

Comment: Is there anyway to do this using the `defaultProps` react method?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing a similar issue and I found a `method` based solution missing in this discussion therefore i am writing this answer

**There are two cases when you might want to pass default props**

Case 1: when you want to choose defaultProps based on a **Static** value

Case 2: when you want to choose defaultProps based on a **Method**

Solution for `Case 1`

```
class Shape extends Component{
  static defaultProps = {
    colour: 'red',
  }
  render(){
   const {colour} = this.props;
   // Colour will always be 'red' if the parent does not pass it as a prop
   return <p>{colour}</p>;
  }
}
```

solution for `Case 2`

```
class Shape extends Component{
  calcArea = () => {
    console.log("Area is x");
  }
  render(){
   const {calcArea} = this.props;
   // calcArea will be evaluated from props then from the class method
   return <button onClick={calcArea || this.caclArea}></button>;
  }
}
```